# Data added from a popup is not visible until a component is manually refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

On adding some comments into a popup the newly added comments should be visible as indicator to screen from where popup is called, but in my case after adding a comment data to the popup, parent page if not getting refreshed to do so i have to manually refresh the page

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="mismatchbox" *ngFor="let data of investigateData" >
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="chat_btn fancybox-effects-d" (click)="showCommentDialog(data)">
  <span class="countIndicator" *ngIf="data?.commentsCount !== 0"></span>
</div>
```

This method will open popup:

```
  @Input() investigateData: any;

       showCommentDialog(comments) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('investigativeName', comments.investigateName);
    this.dialogService.addDialog(ScreeningCommentDialog, {
      objScreeningProvider: comments ? comments : new ScreeningProvider()
    }).subscribe((res) => {
      if(res){
        this.getCommentsCount(comments.investigateName);

      }
    });
    this.sharedataService.setdialogService(this.dialogService);

  }
```

> Get commentCount method

```
 getCommentsCount(type){
    this.commentService.getAlertDetailsCommentsCount(this.alertDetails['alertId'],((this.sessionStorage.getItem('watchListName'))+'_'+type), 'Alert Details', 'MONITORING').subscribe(obj => {
       if(obj) {
         this.investigateData.forEach( investigativeData => {
           if(investigativeData.investigateName === type){
             investigativeData.commentsCount = obj.length;
           }
         });
       }
    });
```

Comment: did you experiment with https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef ?

Comment: @Ayyash i am new to angular I don’t know these things. Do u have any better solution

Comment: well, it is just a technique, it might not fix your problem. what does "getCommentsCount" function do?

Comment: @Ayyash it brings the number of cmments and bind it to parent component to display indicator

Comment: tell me, when u close the dialog or click on any other link that does not route, like focus on a field, does the count gets updated? (magically)

Comment: Count gets updated but its only visible when I navigate from one page to other

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're handling the order of operations incorrectly. When the component is clicked, this `showCommentDialog` method is executed. You set the value to session storage, then call the `addDialog` method on the `dialogService` and pass in a component with some data, then subscribe to the result of that.

It's unclear what you intend to happen in that dialog, but it seems that until that dialog closes, it's not going to populate the observable that you're subscribing to, and until that value is pushed, `subscribe` will not be called to execute the interval you've got in place.

#### Option 1

The easiest approach here is possibly to just take the input value you've got in your component and pass it down to your child component in its own `@Input`. Angular will handle the change tracking and update across each component.

You still haven't posted what your `ScreeningCommentDialog` looks like nor the details of your `dialogService`, so I'm going to have to make some assumptions here, but the gist looks like:

```
this.dialogService.addDialog(ScreeningCommentDialog, {
  objScreeningProvider: comments ? comments : new ScreeningProvider(),
  investigateData: this.investigateData  
})
```

Assuming that the addDialog is creating an instance of the `ScreeningCommentDialog`, you provide your investigateDatavalue to inject into an @Input property exposed on this subsequent provider. For example, this might look like this within your service:

```
//Service constructor for DI injection
constructor(private _cr: ComponentResolver)
//...
public addDialog(type: any, data: any): Observable<string> //Hard to say what type this returns from your sample
{
  this._cr.resolveComponent(type).then(factory => {
    let componentRef = this.childContainer.createComponent(factory);
    //This line will write the value of your local investigateDatavalue to an @Input property on the new component instance
    componentRef.instance.iData = this.investigateData; //Renamed for ease in understanding relationship between my exmaples
  });
}
```

And like you have in your current component, you'd need to put an `@Input` property on your `ScreeningCommentDialog` component.

```
@Input() iData: any;
```

Then, when you imperatively create the new component, you'll also write to its own input property and continue to pass that data through.

#### Option 2

Why not create a static subject on the `ScreeningCommentDialog` component that the component subscribes to when it loads to the page and then use this component to push values to the subject whenever you have an update. This would make for a slightly more rigid approach to what you're aiming to do, but not much moreso than the maintenance of handling a chain of dependent @Input properties across several components.

On your subsequent `ScreeningCommentDialog` component, create something like this (an [AsyncSubject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/AsyncSubject) being used so it recalls the last value provided it):

```
public static investigateData = new AsyncSubject<any>();
```

Set up anything that uses this value to simply subscribe to this subject:

```
ScreeningCommentDialog.subscribe(val => {
  //Do something with it
});
```

In your posted component above, utilize the ngOnChanges method to identify when your input property changes, then use that call to push new data to the static subject on your dialog.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  ScreeningCommentDialog.investigateData.next(changes.investigateData.currentValue);
}
```

Comment: I can't call any service as data is getting binded from @Input property on top of my component => @Input() investigateData: any;

Comment: Fair, but that doesn't change the point of my answer. Your service doesn't receive any updates because 1) your interval callback isn't actually doing anything with `this.investigateData` every 300ms and 2) your callback isn't firing until the addDialog method completes and pushes back data. RXJS runs lazily, so until it receives data, it's not proactively calling anything.

Comment: I've use interval just fr testing purpose

Comment: @Naman I've suggested another option, 1, that would be simpler. Just as you have an `@Input` to this component, so too should you just set up an `@Input` to your `ScreeningCommentDialog` component and then just pass that value through. The other option would be difficult to communicate since you don't share a minimal example of that other component here.

Comment: I didnt get what do you mean by just pass that value through ?

Comment: I've expanded the approaches in both option 1 and option 2 with specific examples